# Помогите понять почему javac -cp не компилирует класс?

Tags: java, javac

У меня есть java - класс Main2 по пути  C:\learn\db\base\mine

Сам класс выглядит примерно так

```
package base.mine;

public class Main2{
      public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Animal> a = new ArrayList<>();
        a.add(new Animal("kingoroo", true, false, true));
        a.add(new Animal("snake", false, true, false));
        a.add(new Animal("fox", true, false, true));

        print(a, new HopeChecker());
        print();
        print(a, new HairsChecker());
        print();
        print(a, new SwimChecker());
    }

    private static void print(){
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static void print(List<Animal> a, Checker checker){
        for (Animal item: a){
            if (checker.test(a)){
               System.out.println(item.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
/* kingoroo fox */
/* kingoroo fox */
/* snake */
```

Если пытаюсь собрать проект из корня проекта используя командную строку - получаю ошибку

То есть из директории

> C:\learn\db>

Запускаю так

```
C:\learn\db>javac -cp "C:\learn\db\base\mine" Main2.java
```

и вижу, такую ошибку

```
C:\learn\db>javac -cp "C:\learn\db\base\mine" Main2.java
javac: file not found: Main2.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

Почему не компилируется?

Comment: Ключ `-cp` указывает пути, в которых компилятор ищет классы зависимостей, а не исходные файлы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Компиляция файла:**

При компиляции класса из исходников (посредством консольной утилиты `javac`) необходимо указать до него путь (относительный или абсолютный).

Ваш пример с использованием абсолютного пути:

`javac -d target C:/learn/db/base/mine/HelloWorld.java`

Ваш пример с использованием относительного пути (относительно каталога, в котором находится ваш `package` с именем `base`):

`javac -d target ./base/mine/HelloWorld.java`

В примерах выше скомпилированные файлы (`.class`-файлы) будут складываться в каталог с именем `target` (`-d target`), что рекомендуется во избежание смешивания исходного кода и результата сборки (байткода).

*Что вы делали не так:* стоит обратить внимание, что вы пытались использовать параметр `-cp` (он же `-classpath`) при компиляции, но данный параметр используется лишь для указания зависимостей (артефактов, содержащих скомпилированные не ваши классы, которые вы используете у себя в коде, примером такого артефакта может являться `.jar`-файл или каталог, содержащий `.class`-файлы, включая вложенность согласно их `package`'ам).

---

**Запуск скомпилированного файла:**

Для запуска скомпилированного файла (посредством консольной утилиты `java`) необходимо указать путь до каталога, в который производилась сборка (в нашем случае, `-classpath ./target`, или же `-cp ./target`):

`java -classpath ./target base.mine.HelloWorld`

---

**Что почитать:**

Для более полного понимания происходящего вам следует почитать базовые мануалы для работы с консольными утилитами в Java, скорее всего, вам подойдет [вот эта статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/125210/).